# Como criar algoritmo de árvore de natal em PHP

Tags: php, algoritmo

Estou fazendo o seguinte código, porém o PHP não soma e atribui zero:

```
<?php
$linha = "*";
for($i = 0; $i < 6; $i++){
    echo($linha)."<br>";
    $linha += "*"; //aqui o php nao soma
}
?>
```

A saída desse código era pra ser:

```
*
**
***
****
```

Porém sai assim:

```
0
0
0
0
0
0
```

Alguém pode me ajudar?

Comment: Obrigado Marcelo Bonifazio por editar

Comment: += como assim???

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você esta querendo concatenar `strings`, para isso você usa o `.` não o `+` em php.

Basta alterar a seguinte linha `$linha += "*";` para `$linha .= "*";`:

```
$linha = "*";
for($i = 0; $i < 6; $i++){
    echo($linha)."<br>";
    $linha .= "*";
}
```

---

Uma breve explicação:

O operador `.=` em PHP é utilizado para concatenação de variáveis, exp: `$a .= $b` pode ser reescrito como: `$a = $a . $b`. E é esperado que se tenha o seguinte: `string .= string`.

O operador `+=` em PHP é utilizado para a operação aritmética de soma de variáveis, exp: `$a += $b` pode ser reescrito como: `$a = $a + $b`. E é esperado que se tenha o seguinte: `integer += integer`.

Desse modo, com o operador aritmético `+=`, por mais que o valor esteja em parentes, dando a entender que é uma string e não um valor numérico, é feita a conversão de `string` para `integer`. Como pode ser visto com o seguinte teste:

```
echo "<b>Teste com .= </b><br/><br/>";
$linha = "Isso é";
echo "Valor antigo: ". $linha." <br/>Tipo antigo: ".gettype($linha)."<br/><br/>";
$linha .= " um teste";
echo "Novo valor: ". $linha." <br/>Tipo novo: ".gettype($linha)."<br/><br/>";
echo "<b>Teste com +=</b><br/><br/>";
$linha = "Isso é";
echo "Valor antigo: ". $linha." <br/>Tipo antigo: ".gettype($linha)."<br/><br/>";
$linha += " um teste";
echo "Novo valor: ". $linha." <br/>Tipo novo: ".gettype($linha)."<br/><br/>";
echo "<b>Outro teste com +=</b><br/><br/>";
$linha = "4";
echo "Valor antigo: ". $linha." <br/>Tipo antigo: ".gettype($linha)."<br/><br/>";
$linha += "10";
echo "Novo valor: ". $linha." <br/>Tipo novo: ".gettype($linha)."<br/>";
```

Isso deve imprimir:

> Teste com .=
>
> Valor antigo: Isso é  Tipo antigo: string
>
> Novo valor: Isso é um teste  Tipo novo: string
>
> Teste com +=
>
> Valor antigo: Isso é  Tipo antigo: string
>
> Novo valor: 0  Tipo novo: integer
>
> Outro teste com +=
>
> Valor antigo: 4  Tipo antigo: string
>
> Novo valor: 14  Tipo novo: integer

Comment: Obrigado Marcelo Bonifazio

Comment: @EversonSouzadeAraujo se a resposta resolveu inteiramente sua pergunta, lembre-se de votar positivo e marcar a pergunta como aceita, clicando no sinal verde abaixo do mecanismo de votação.

Comment: quando clico diz que não tenho permissão

Comment: @EversonSouzadeAraujo Pra votar você já tem, acho que pra aceitar a resposta tem um tempo mínimo que tem que esperar. Essa foi bem rápida né. :)

Comment: era isso mesmo  @gustavox deu certo, obg